# Listing filesystem differences between a Docker image and one of its ancestors

Tags: docker, audit

I asked a [similar question](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/6347/11179) a few minutes ago, and I found the `docker diff` command that shows the differences in the file system between a *container* and its *base image*. But I realized afterward my need is more complex than that.

I have a Docker image, and I know that Docker image was build from a given base image. Is there a way to list the filesystem changes between those two *images*?

Here is an example:

```
sh$ sudo docker image ls
REPOSITORY                    TAG                 IMAGE ID
rogueimage                    latest              77a21f689dcd
ubuntu                        18.04               47b19964fb50
```

I know `rogueimage:latest` is based on `ubuntu:18.04` but I would like to know the filesystem difference between the two images. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was already a [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21200304/docker-how-to-show-the-diffs-between-2-images) about that topic, but the answers didn't really help me. The [container-diff](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/container-diff) tools was the most promising solution, but I would have preferred not relying on a third-party tool.

Finally, since docker can export an archive of a *container* filesystem, I end up with this solution:

```
BASE_CID=$(sudo docker create ubuntu:18.04)
TARGET_CID=$(sudo docker create rogueimage:latest)

sudo docker export "${BASE_CID}" | tar tv > base.filelist
sudo docker export "${TARGET_CID}" | tar tv > target.filelist
```

Then using your favorite diff tool you can examine the difference:

```
vimdiff {base,target}.filelist
```